# How to change the canonical function for category page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, canonical

How to add **custom url**  Using **canonical function**

Code:

```
if ($this->_categoryHelper->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
    $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
    $category->getUrl(),
    'canonical',
   ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
  );
}
```

Can any one help i want to add page limit to given url

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245313/magento-2-override-product-canonical-url